# How to execute Appium test cases with Appcelerator Alloy

Tags: automated-tests, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile, appium

I am using Appium.app available on the store and website. I am able to successfully load .app and connect appium with Simulator through which .app can be run on Simulator and logs can be displayed in Appium Inspector. I am able to see available elements in Inspector and besides that Screenshot of Simulator is showing up from which I can select elements.

This way I am able to prepare some test cases but in some youtube videos I see that that screenshot in Appium Inspector updates itself when I carry out some Tap, Swipe, etc. actions but in my Appium Inspector the screenshot is not being updated.

But after I generated automated test cases, how to write them inside Alloy app so we can automate testing in development testing itself. Can anyone help me how to integrate automated test cases in Alloy apps?